# Python unexpected behaviour with list.append()

Tags: python, list, append, behavior

I was working with a machine learning model and I tried to append his output in a list for each element in antoher list.
I used a for loop but it seems like the loop jumps the first index and repeats the last ones:

```
x = [[0.12], [0.36], [0.48]]

print(model.run(x[0]))    #this prints [-0.0006]
print(model.run(x[1]))    #this prints [-0.0018]
print(model.run(x[2]))    #this prints [-0.0024]

out_values = []

for value in x:
    out_values.append(model.run(value)) 

print(out_values)   #this should print [[-0.0012], [-0.0018], [-0.0024]]
# but it actually prints [[-0.0018], [-0.0024], [-0.0024]]
```

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the model.run() output since the first print statements worked perfectly
It must be something related to out_values.append(), because if I run:

```
x = [[0.12], [0.36], [0.48]]

out_values = []

out_values.append(model.run(x[0]))
out_values.append(model.run(x[1]))
out_values.append(model.run(x[2]))

print(out_values) # the result I get is still [[-0.0018], [-0.0024], [-0.0024]]
```

In my opinion it wasn't supposed to jump over model.run(x[0]) and repeat model.run(x[2]) twice

Is this documented or supposed to happen? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is `model.run` a pure function, or does the model update each time it runs, meaning you'll get different results by calling it with the same set of values repeatedly?  Does it mutate its input?

Comment: Yes, at each run the model is going to re-create it's weights so when I run model.run(x), kill the program and run it again, it surely will give me a different result. However if I call model.run(x) twice in the same program, it's gonna return the same result as long as x value doesn't change

Comment: You'll need to share the code of `model.run` for me to be sure, but based on the behavior you're seeing, I'm pretty sure that it's returning references to mutable state within the model.

Comment: I don't think so because the first prints always show different results as it should be, but anyway here you can run it by yourself:
https://repl.it/@HugoSouza1/smll#test.py

Comment: Mutating the result doesn't affect the `print` calls, but it does affect any reference you keep to the result (whether in a list or any other way).  To test it out and completely eliminate any theory that `append` is somehow misbehaving, you could try doing `ans0 = model.run(x[0])` `ans1 = model.run(x[1])1` `ans2 = model.run(x[2])` and then examining the value of `ans0`.

Comment: ah -- yes, the return value of `model.run` is a reference to a list inside the `layers`, which in turn is mutated by each call to `feedforward`.  So every time you run the model, the previous return values mutate -- in addition, the caller is able to modify the model by mutating the return value you gave it!  Lots of potential for fun bugs.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that `model.run` is returning a reference to mutable state within the model which is updated on successive `run` calls -- that's why there's a difference between what you print immediately after the `run` and what ends up in the list after additional calls.  I.e. the value is correct at the time you call `append`, but it changes after the fact.  When you call `model.run(x[2])`, it's modifying and returning the list that it returned when you called `model.run(x[1])`, and at some point it also modifies the list that was returned for `x[0]`.  (This is not good behavior IMO -- if `model` is from an external library, hopefully it's at least documented in the API that you should not keep references to the return value of `run`!  Otherwise it's just plain diabolical.)

To work around this problem so that you can keep each result as it was originally returned, make a copy of each result as you get it:

```
out_values = [model.run(value).copy() for value in x]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. To be honest I wrote this API myself and I didn't know about this behaviour envolving model.run(). I'll try to fix it. Thanks for the advices!!!!

Comment: The better fix is to do the `copy` inside the implementation of `run()` as you return the result!  That way you don't need to remember to do it at every call site.

Comment: I might even recommend doing the same inside e.g. `Dense` -- in general you don't want to return a list that is part of your own state, because then any change you make will mess with data that the caller should expect to be in charge of, *and* the caller is able to change the list and mess with your state in return!  In this case you're returning that reference through multiple callers before it gets messed with, which makes it extra confusing to debug.

Comment: To see what I mean, do `ans = model.run(x[0])` and then `ans[:] = "haha I broke your model"` (and then see what happens when you call `model.run()` again)

Answer (score 0):

It will not skip any value or repeat any other value twice. Your model.run must be returning those values only. To remove that doubt, can you update the code to print the return value and print that like so:

```
for value in x:
    ans = model.run(value)
    print(ans)
    out_values.append(ans)
```

Can you show output for above?

Comment: `[0.07644]
[0.22932]
[0.30576]
[[0.22932], [0.30576], [0.30576]] `

the first three lines are the ans value, and the last one is out_values after the loop. Note that the values had changed because each run model.run(x) returns a different value, but the problem still happens, the list still skipped the x[0] and repeated the last values

Answer (score 0):

can you use this code instead?

```
x = (0.12, 0.36, 0.48)

print(x[0])    #this prints [-0.0006]
print(x[1])    #this prints [-0.0018]
print(x[2])    #this prints [-0.0024]

out_values = []

out_values = set(x)

print(out_values)
```

it'll include all x in the out_values

Comment: Actually I cannot because I need to get the model.run() result for each value in x before I append it to out_values. And each member of x should be inside a list or model.run() will raise an Exception